# React Native fails to build for Android [solved]

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, expo

I have an expo react-native project that I've been working on for a long time. It runs fine in simulator and Expo go. Now when attempting to build it for Android i get errors that I don't understand or manage to fix.

I have tried to build a fresh expo project with similar dependencies/package.json file (nativewind, expo-router,....) and it works fine. So I think that my Android Studio setup is working.

Build command  `eas build --platform android --profile preview --local`

The error I get

```
[RUN_GRADLEW] Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
[RUN_GRADLEW] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[RUN_GRADLEW] * What went wrong:
[RUN_GRADLEW] Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file '/private/var/folders/fz/vmy1tl710s5__w3csgqd49t40000gp/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/609de72a-df60-4fb8-9296-c0af850bf3d4/build/android/settings.gradle' (/Users/adm/.gradle/caches/8.0.1/scripts/arlfm39hu840rj11qgqf3tuor).
[RUN_GRADLEW] > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 65
[RUN_GRADLEW] * Try:
[RUN_GRADLEW] > Run with
[RUN_GRADLEW] --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
[RUN_GRADLEW] > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
[RUN_GRADLEW] >
[RUN_GRADLEW] Run with --scan to get full insights.
[RUN_GRADLEW] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[RUN_GRADLEW] BUILD FAILED
[RUN_GRADLEW] in 37s
[RUN_GRADLEW] Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.
```

In scans.gradle.com i get with `/gradlew assembleRelease --stacktrace  --scan --warning-mode all`

```
> Resource compilation failed (Failed to compile values resource file /Users/adm/learn23/star/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/release/mergeReleaseResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml. Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@66d999cd.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@48822ade.). Check logs for more details.
  > Failed to compile values resource file /Users/adm/learn23/star/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/release/mergeReleaseResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml
    > Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@66d999cd.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@48822ade.
```

It appears that there is an error in `values.xml`

```
[RUN_GRADLEW] /Users/adm/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7afdb9c874b781c7e99aca63d43fa0e1/transformed/appcompat-1.4.1/res/values/values.xml:63:4: Invalid <color> for given resource value.
```

Referring to invalid colors. This xml file gets generated for me. And I don't find those colors referred in my codebase

```
<color name="button_material_dark">#ff5a595b</color> // line 26 this is ok
<color name="button_material_light">#ffd6d7d7</color> //line 27 This fails 
...
<color name="secondary_text_disabled_material_light">#24000000</color> // line 63 fails
```

Any ideas on what might be wrong?

The whole `values.xml` file is at https://gist.github.com/exoer/389e3e0d5958e9cb0ba0854f63a29abf

Comment: Share the whole xml file.

Comment: I found the error and solution. In my `app.json` file I had an illegal value for a color. `splashImage: {"backgroundColor": "#ddddd"}` - should be #dddddd. Took me 5 days .